# Prevent graphql query on page load

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Everytime I open my page, my page will make query to graphql. How do I prevent the query on page load because I only want the query to happen when user click Search button.

[image]

Here is my component and graphql code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
   this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  submit() {
   this.props.searchData.refetch({ asset_type: this.state.value})
  }

  render() {
   <div>
    <Input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <button onClick={() => { this.submit(); }} >
     <span>Search</span>
    </button>
   </div>
  // other html element
  }

PlacementSearch.propTypes = {
  searchData: PropTypes.shape({
    refetch: PropTypes.function,
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

const queryVariable = gql`
  query RootQuery($asset_type: String) {
    am {
      assets(asset_type: $asset_type) {
        data {
          uuid
          label
          asset_type
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(queryVariable, {
  name: 'searchData',
  skip: props => props.url.stopQuery,
  options: { variables: { asset_type: '' } },
})(PlacementSearch);
```

From the docs, using `skip` could prevent the queries but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is how I do it for now but I have no idea how can I change the skip to false.

```
props.url.stopQuery = true;
<PlacementSearch url={props.url} />
```

How do I check the page has finished loading and then changing `skip` to `false`. I'm not even sure whether I'm taking the right approach by using `skip`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue. Did you ever figure how to prevent query firing on page load?